# imdb top 250 movies scraper -- how to get results only from year 2000 and up?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Python (and coding in general) and scrapy so my knowledge of both is basic/limited (I am basically just copying code from various Google searches).

I managed to come up with a working code so far:

```
import scrapy

class imdb_project(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/chart/top']

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.css('.titleColumn a'):
            print(i.css('::text').get())
```

this code is working just fine. I am able to scrape all 250 movie titles on https://www.imdb.com/chart/top

Now, I would like to only scrape movie titles from the same page only if the movie came out in the year 2000 and up.

You can see [here](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top) that the year is displayed right after the movie title. This should be pretty easy to do but for the life of me I cannot find a similar example on Google or even here on Stack Overflow to get me started in solving this.

I am thinking it should be something simple like:

```
if movie_year >= 2000:
    then run the 'for' loop above
```

...but I do not know how to code the above in Python. Any help (if possible, no regex or xpath please)?

Comment: You should scrap from their advanced search. But, I just add important notes: Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted in: https://www.imdb.com/conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMDb forbids scraping, but here is what it would look like if *theoretically* you were allowed to scrape from their site:

```
import scrapy

class imdb_project(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/chart/top']

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.css('.titleColumn'):
            title = i.css('a::text').get()
            year = i.css('.secondaryInfo::text').get()[1:-1] 

            if int(year) >= 2000:
                # or you could just do title if you don't
                # want the year
                print("{0} ({1})".format(title, year))
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what `[1:-1]` does?

Comment: It is called string slicing, what it does in this case is it slices of the two brackets that parenthesise the year. It starts at index 1 of the string-which is the second character- and ends at index -1 which is the second to last character